# Xcode Internal Error - Uncaught Exception - Attempt to allocate *** bytes for CFString Failed

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4

I am having a bit of a frustrating Monday morning. I started working in my Xcode project and decided to test a minor change I had made to the code, on my iPad 2.

The code compiles fine, but every time it gets to the "installing" stage, I get the spinning beach ball and then my memory gets eaten up until I get the Internal Error message pop-up.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Internal Error Message]

I am completely stumped as to why I am now getting this. Here is the Console log:

```
5/2/11 11:29:52 AM  Xcode[1251] [MT] Uncaught Exception:
Attempt to allocate 6715168 bytes for CFString failed

Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010012d796 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x0000000102d5f0f3 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x000000010042767d _NSSearchForNameInPath (in Foundation)
  3  0x000000010007f391 _CFRuntimeCreateInstance (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x000000010008156f __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00000001000849fb CFStringCreateCopy (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x000000010030ecff -[NSCFString copyWithZone:] (in Foundation)
  7  0x0000000130c31168 __55-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConsoleController initWithDeviceRef:]_block_invoke_0 (in DTDeviceKit)
  8  0x0000000130c31671 __55-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConsoleController initWithDeviceRef:]_block_invoke_048 (in DTDeviceKit)
  9  0x0000000102b40284 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 10  0x0000000102b1edf2 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 11  0x0000000102b1f69f _dispatch_queue_serial_drain_till_empty (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 12  0x0000000102b5243c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 13  0x00000001000c90c8 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 14  0x00000001000c7dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 15  0x00000001044537ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 16  0x00000001044535f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 17  0x00000001044534ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 18  0x000000010074de64 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 19  0x000000010074d7a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 20  0x000000010071348b -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 21  0x000000010070c1a8 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 22  0x0000000100001694
 23  0x0000000000000002
```

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Oh dear, that's never any fun! Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: So I reloaded Xcode and tried again. It seems to be working moderately well, but I notice that it just keeps climbing in its memory allocations (I'm checking this via Activity Monitor). If I let it continue to run, it climbs all the way up until I run out of memory. (I have 4GB of Memory!) What the heck is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after a long and stressful day of troubleshooting, I figured it out (sort of). As Oscar Hierro pointed out, this is a problem with the iPad 2. One reason it took me so long to narrow it down to this, was I never even suspected that AN APPLE DEVICE would be causing this issue.

For all who are interested, these are the steps I took to resolve this:

(In the order I performed these in)

—Reinstalled The SDK *~ Didn't Help*

—Deleted Xcode preferences *~ Didn't Help*

—Tried Numerous Projects. *All had similar results.*

—Deleted Xcode preferences, and cached files. *~ Didn't Help*

—Uninstalled the Dev Tools via Terminal and reinstalled the SDK. *~ Didn't Help*

—Got discouraged and nearly gave up. *~ Didn't Help*

—Decided to stop testing on the iPad 2. *~ Finally Helped*

So what a colleague finally suggested was that we close all apps running in the background (multi-tasking). To my great surprise, it worked! So I can't tell you why this was happening, but I can tell you that closing all the apps on the iPad 2 fixed the problem.

As a side-note, my iPad 2 is running 4.3.2—the latest iOS at this time. I would love to read any thoughts someone might have of why this seemingly fluke bug was happening.

Comment: This "bug", or whatever we are calling it, is not exclusive to the iPad 2. I just experienced it again with the original iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, also since yesterday Monday, and it is definitely related to the iPad 2. If I disconnect the device, Xcode works fine, but as soon as I connect it again Xcode starts using more and more CPU and memory until it eventually crashes. The issue doesn't seem to happen when I connect an older iPad (1st gen).

I'm updating my iPad 2 from 4.3.1 to 4.3.2 as I write this. Will see if that fixes the issue (somehow I doubt it).

Comment: So as an status update, after upgrading my iPad 2 to 4.3.2 the problem with Xcode went away, but I suspect, as daveMac pointed out in his own answer, that it is been due to the device being rebooted during the installation rather than to the new version of iOS itself. Probably I should have thought of doing that first, but since I was planning to update it anyway :)